# <selenium >Cannot move to the web elements present in the child window

Tags: selenium

```
<input name="ucCreateOrganization$txtName" type="text" maxlength="200" 
    id="ucCreateOrganization_txtName" class="Text" autocomplete="off" 
    data-field-value="Name" placeholder="Portfolio Name *"
    onblur="EnableDisableCreateButton()" wemi-required=""
    maxlengthreadonly="200" style="height:27px;" title="">
```

This is the text field, which is present in the child window. We cannot navigate to the child window and also we cannot play with the web elements in the child window. We have tried with CSS-selector as well as XPath. But it's not working.

Comment: <input name="ucCreateOrganization$txtName" type="text" maxlength="200" id="ucCreateOrganization_txtName" class="Text" autocomplete="off" data-field-value="Name" placeholder="Portfolio Name *" onblur="EnableDisableCreateButton()" wemi-required="" maxlengthreadonly="200" style="height:27px;" title="">   - This is the html code

Comment: Need to format your code. Put the comment in your question and format it such that it is readable.

Comment: is child window opens new tab or new window?

Comment: Please post the HTML and your code both in question and not in comments

Comment: That is the child window(background i.e main window is read only mode, not a  new window or new tab .

Comment: show the code you tried.

Comment: may the child the window is inside the iframe/frame. please check the input element is inside iframe.

Comment: You mentioned that you "cannot navigate to the child window".  Well, you must do that before you can access the element in that window.  What do you mean by "child window".  Is a new browser window opened?  In either case, please show us the code that you are using to interact with the browser, that's the best way we can help you.